# Transparent hole in wxFrame background

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

Is there a way to cut a transparent rectangle in the background of a wxFrame to see the desktop or other windows behind that rect?

Custom shape is not an option since I want to capture mouse events there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only possibilities here are using a custom shape or `SetTransparent()` but the latter can only set the transparency uniformly.

`SetTransparent()` could probably be extended to be more flexible, but so far nobody has done it.